# What mail service errors can AppEngine produce?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I would like to control and embed my `send()` calls in a try/except, but I'm not sure of what errors it can produce.

Looking around the SDK, it seems like MailServiceError is the one, but not sure since I don't know how to test an error like that.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the exceptions that can be thrown by a call to send(): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/exceptions

Here's an example of how you could catch these:

```
from google3.apphosting.api import mail

# other code to create 'message' here
try:
  message.send()
except mail.InvalidSender, e:
  # Do something special for an invalid sender error
  pass
except mail.Error, e:
  # This will catch all the other exceptions in the doc above.
  pass
```

Comment: Great, i dont know why i skipped that page in docs. Thanks for the quick answer.