# Continue with script when error with email google apps

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the below code in a loop to send emails from spreadsheets that are filled by users:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
```

The problem is that users sometimes have mistake with the email address and when the script run and find incorrect email address it halts the script.

Is there away to continue the loop and skip the error? Can anyone advise me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to validate the email address like. I use this one:

```
regex_mail = re.compile('^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_.\-]*@([a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,6})$')
```

And you can use Python exception handling with try-except for handling script errors. See this question:
[What mail service errors can AppEngine produce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283352/what-mail-service-errors-can-appengine-produce)

Answer (score 0):

If users are filling the spreadsheet by using a Google Form, you should enable validation for the email field. This won't ensure that the address exists, only that it is properly formed, but should avoid the error you are seeing.

It would still be smart to validate before sending, using regex as voscausa suggests.

Using `validateEmail()` from [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript/46181#46181):

```
if (validateEmail(Email)) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
}
```